# MMdrawerCOntroller - Load view in center view with transition

Tags: ios, swift, mmdrawercontroller

TL;DR :

> I want to be able to load views in the center either from the left side
>   MMdrawer menu or from the app home page.

I have an app with a left side drawer (MMdrawerController), displaying a menu.

The menu is working fine, i can load my diferents views in the center like this :

```
   var ListeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListeViewController") as! ListeViewController

        var listeHCollectionViewNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ListeVC )

        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = listeCollectionViewNavController
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It works fine.

My problem is, my app is starting on a view, with a presentation text and 3 big buttons (basically the most used features of the app).

These button target view that i also target with the left side menu.

With this :

```
appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = listeHiraganasCollectionViewNavController
```

I can load in the center any view, but no transition or animation available.

If i use a segue or a push programatically, my view loads but my MMdrawer is no longer available on the view that just loaded, because i loaded it without using the MMDrawer methods i think.

How could i do that?

If anyone has an idea...
Thanks in advance.

Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution.

I used a story board segue directly to the view controller i'm targeting and not its nav controller (push).

But i targeted the nav controller from my menu inside mmdrawer.

I load the navbars from code eitherway

Seems to work